# Test.setMock working in Scratch org but not in sandbox Org

Tags: batch, salesforcedx, scheduled-apex, dml, httpcalloutmock

We have batch class used to make an API callout and doing Opportunity upsert DML operation in the **Start** method.
Based on the opportunity's return value, we are making another API callout and doing Opportunity upsert DML operation in **Execute** method.

For this action, I'm getting this error "You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out" in sandbox org but not in Scratch org.

As per the salesforce, Start and Execute methods are separate transactions I think. Please advise on this.

Comment: SO that is working fine in scratch org test but not in the sandbox? My theory is it should work even in scratch org?

Comment: assuming this is not a testmethod use case; start and execute are separate transactions so that is not the issue; more likely, sandbox org is doing some DML (including emails) prior to the callout because of some data condition that is different between sandbox and scratch. Debug log will be instructive